# Portable AC Port in Apartment Wall

Tags: air-conditioning, portable-ac

I recently purchased a [Honeywell portable AC unit](https://www.honeywellstore.com/store/products/portable-air-conditioner-10000-btu-cooling-hl10ceswk.htm) for my apartment but there's two competing issues:

1. I only have a sliding door in my apartment (no windows), and the adapter kit to vent through the window obviously isn't long enough for the height of the door.
2. There *is* a portable AC port in the wall (which I would prefer to use), but the diameter of the Honeywell tubing is 6", and the interior diameter of the wall port is about 5.5". There is also a gradual extrusion away from the wall port with a diameter about 6".

I have been going insane trying to find any information on standardized apartment wall AC ports, and literally any search I try gives me results that are either "10 best AC units to buy for apartments" or imply that I would drill a hole myself to match the size of the tubing. For example, I tried searching "apartment portable ac wall vent". I have been searching for at least 3-4 hours.

So, I have three questions:

1. What is the wall AC port called so I can search it correctly?
2. How do I attach the portable AC tube to the wall port? Do I just use duct tape? I literally have no idea how to safely attach it otherwise and the unit did not come with instructions for wall ports.
3. Should I just give up and purchase a sliding door adapter kit?

I appreciate any help as I am slowly melting!

Here's a picture also. [image]

Comment: Make a plywood panel to sort the door gap - probably cheaper than a door kit but tools, skills and time are also factors...

Comment: Photos of the wall port and the end of the tube would help figure out what would work.

Comment: Added. The tube is collapsable/extendable.

Comment: Using a sliding door is a feature not a bug. It allows you to separate the hot ejection air from condenser intake air.  Eject the hot air near the top and suck condenser  air from the bottom.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - that type of AC only has a single hot hose, separation not required. The cold side is just pulled from the room itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh, dear.  Nature abhors a vacuum.  If the A/C pack is stealing process air from the room, makeup air will re-enter the room through any possible orifice.  Not good.  Aside from other problems with drawing air from ???, that air may be hot and wet, defeating the purpose!  It may even be that same process air coming back through a poorly sealed exit hole lol... talk about banging your head against the wall...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - that's just how they work. Not a lot you can do about it. Ambient air pulls from the room the unit is in, hot air bows out the window, cold air blows into the room. I've never seen any domestic unit more sophisticated than that. Industrial portables, yes, but not domestic. I'm in the UK, btw, where we only discovered aircon in the past decade & it's still very much a rarity in homes ;)

Comment: Not particularly related to the original question, but for the audience here — "dual hose portable air conditioners" for domestic use do exist. They're just not very common compared to single hose units (at least here in the US). (And of course, window units are better than either type for efficiency and noise.)

Answer (score 3):

That does not look like a port intended for connecting any sort of hose, particularly as the rim is rounded over without any provision for sealing or securing. It looks like a round [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(air_and_heating)) that is missing the central diffuser and damper control parts:

[image]

*([Photo by Paul Goyette on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Central_ventilation_tube.jpg), CC-BY-SA license)*

Do not connect your air conditioner to it as this will most likely disrupt the building's ventilation system (sending your hot exhaust air to other people's apartments) and also probably have flow restriction that will reduce your AC's performance.

Instead, buy an aftermarket sliding door vent kit.

Answer (score 2):

I have this in my condo also. The white cap thing is held in by a clamp, you pull on the middle of the 3 "branches" it will come out easy. Then put your hose in, you should see a round flap to the outside. It was a simple set up time for me.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense _except_ that the OP indicated a hose diameter of 6" and a port internal diameter of 5.5". He may need an adapter of some sort.